# To restore queue members

Tags: c#

Hi guys i have such loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        if (passwords.Count == 0)
        {
            proxy_loop = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            password = passwords.Dequeu();
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

When the loop ends I have to restore the content (that was on the beginning) of passwords Queue

Comment: what is your  question?

Comment: The fact that you have the inside of your loop wrapped in a lock makes me think that what you want to do (restore the queue) could have lots of gotchas if multiple threads are involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Queue backup = (Queue) passwords.Clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; 6++)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (passwords.Count == 0)
                {
                    proxy_loop = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string password = (string) passwords.Dequeue();

                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        passwords = backup;
```

Comment: +1 Depending on the overall usage/context (which, admittedly, we don't have) it might make more sense to use the `backup` within the loop and never mutate the `passwords` Queue.

Comment: its not a clean / efficient way if threading is implemented, but i think will do the job!

Comment: To add to what @ChrisSinclair said, another advantage to operating on backup is that you would no longer need the lock in the loop (just one around the Clone). As you have it, you may need to wrap your entire block of code in a lock, otherwise if the first thread is halfway through the for loop, and another thread comes along and does the same, it will make a backup using the partially modified passwords. Use of ConcurrentQueue might also help.